# Не могу создать новый публичный репозиторий в github

Tags: git, github

При попытке создать новый публичный репозиторий в github выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
Cannot upgrade without any billing information
```

Только вчера создал другой новый репозиторий и никаких проблем с billing information не было.

Comment: а можно более детально? Какой командой создавали новый репозиторий вчера, какой создаете сегодня? Впечатление буд-то вы пытаетесь проапдейтить информацию во вчерашнем.

Comment: возможно, в промежутке вы [конвертировали свою персональную учётную запись в учётную запись организации](https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization/). тогда вам следует заполнить профайл необходимой информацией.

Comment: да нет, судя по всем какой-то глюк был на их сервере. Сейчас все хорошо. Спасибо за ответы.